# How to set only one option in jquery chosen multi select when I submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, multi-select, jquery-chosen

I am using the Jquery Chosen plugin here I want to allow  maximum number of options one. in drop-down it have many option, even if I submit with more then one option it should throw the error like please select one option only.

Here in this scenario i want to allow only one option in multi-select dropdown. I'm unable to control the one option anyone can you please help me how to validation the option in multi-select.

```js
$('.chosen-select').chosen()
  .on('change', function(evt, params) {
    max_selected_options = 1;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" integrity="sha512-yVvxUQV0QESBt1SyZbNJMAwyKvFTLMyXSyBHDO4BG5t7k/Lw34tyqlSDlKIrIENIzCl+RVUNjmCPG+V/GMesRw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-rMGGF4wg1R73ehtnxXBt5mbUfN9JUJwbk21KMlnLZDJh7BkPmeovBuddZCENJddHYYMkCh9hPFnPmS9sspki8g==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select data-placeholder="Choose..." class="chosen-select" multiple="" name="milestone">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I fixed your snippet to actually register chosen

Comment: It should allow multiple options but when I click on submit button then only it should throw the error alert like please select only one option

Comment: Why don't you prevent it from selecting multiple items?

Comment: WHY do you have a multiple select if you only allow one? Sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: I want to write a validation for jquery chosen multi-select dropdown. if multi-select dropdown holding  more then one option in that dropdown, when I click on submit button
it should throw the error message like please select only one option.

Comment: You do not explain WHY you want to allow multiple selections and then not allow multiple selections!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `multiple` attribute on `select` tag. here is an example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" integrity="sha512-yVvxUQV0QESBt1SyZbNJMAwyKvFTLMyXSyBHDO4BG5t7k/Lw34tyqlSDlKIrIENIzCl+RVUNjmCPG+V/GMesRw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-rMGGF4wg1R73ehtnxXBt5mbUfN9JUJwbk21KMlnLZDJh7BkPmeovBuddZCENJddHYYMkCh9hPFnPmS9sspki8g==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form id="myForm">
<select data-placeholder="Choose..." multiple class="chosen-select" name="milestone">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<script>
 let choosen = $(".chosen-select").chosen({width: "200px"});
 
 $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const form = e.target;
  const milestones = $(form.elements.milestone).val();
  if(milestones.length > 1) alert('error');
  else alert('success')
 })
</script>
```

Comment: `$('.chosen-select').chosen({ width: "150px"  })`

Comment: @mplungjan I editet answer, Thanks.

Comment: how to write validation for chose multi-select if drop-down have more then one option for example when I click on submit please update that is your answer.

Comment: I want to write a validation for jquery chosen multi-select dropdown. if multi-select dropdown holding  more then one option in that dropdown, when I click on submit button
it should throw the error message like please select only one option.

Comment: @Anantha I edited my answer, but i couldn't understand why you need a multiple select and define validation to select just one option.